# Play attachment video in email body

Tags: html, email, video

Good morning everyone,

I am looking for a solution, how to play a video file attachment in the email body.
Is there any way how to use f.e. video tag and as a source the attached video file?

I was googling and trying for a long time and it seems it is not possible, but maybe somebody here could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-i-include-music-video-in-my-campaigns/ and (2) http://blog.campaignmaster.co.uk/2012/09/25/using-video-in-email-2/

Answer (score 0):

[It is possible](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2905/html5-and-video-in-email/), but not widely supported using html5's `<video>` tag. It is pretty much limited to Mac clients.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I have found this article before posting my question, but it is from 2009 and lot of things may have changed since then.
However I need to play the attached video and not any embeded video.